# Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a `ListView` where every element in the list contains a TextView and two different Buttons. Something like this:

```
ListView
--------------------
[ImageView][Text][CheckBox][Button]
--------------------
[ImageView][Text][CheckBox][Button]
--------------------
... (and so on) ...
```

With this code I can create an `OnItemClickListener` for the whole item:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onListItemClick: " + position);

        }

    }
});
```

However, I don't want the whole item to be clickable, but only the checkbox and the button of each list element.

So my question is, how do I implement a onClickListener for these two buttons with the following parameters:

- `int id` (some id associated with each item in list)
- `int position` (which is the element in the list on which the button click happened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make baseAdpter to achieve this

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ContactInfo> mlist;
    Context mcontext;


public BluetoothChatadpter(Context context,ArrayList<ChatInfo> mchtlist) {      
        mlist =  mchtlist;
        mcontext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int postion) {
        return mlist.get(postion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup viewgroup){
            View view = null;
            if(convertview == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, null);

                ContactHolder holder = new ContactHolder();

                holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
                holder.txtviewphone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                holder.chkselected = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.check);

                setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // to open the selected file in resp

                  // do your work here
                 }});


    chkselected .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // Toast.makeText(context,// "checked is clicke="+pos, 12).show();
            if (chkselected.isChecked())          
                       {            

                        // do your work here
            } else {

     // do your work here                               
            }
        }
});



            view.setTag(holder);

        }
            else{
                view = convertview;
            }
            ContactHolder holder2 = (ContactHolder) view.getTag();
            holder2.txtviewfirstname.setText(list.get(position).firstname);
            holder2.txtviewphone.setText(list.get(position).phonenumber);
            holder2.chkselected.setChecked(list.get(position).selected);
            return view;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved the same problem in this way:
in the layout.xml of the ListViewItem give the elements a tag, where you want to add the OnClickListener:

```
       android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
       android:tag="CheckBox" />
```

....

```
       android:id="@+id/Button"
       android:tag="Button" />
```

In the code, where your ListView is inflated add the OnClickListener with the following code:

```
       listView.findViewWithTag("CheckBox").setOnClickListener(createCheckBoxOnClickListener(act));
       listView.findViewWithTag("Button").setOnClickListener(createButtonOnClickListener(act));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do this in the `getView` method in your adapter..

Answer (score 0):

easy, just implement the `OnClickListener` for these two buttons, and get the position that you get from `getView()`, make sure you set the position to `final` in order to get it in `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

you can add listeners in your getView() method of Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

dont add onItemClickListener for the listview rather add onClick for your required button and for checkbox do it like this

```
 CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox(this);// find your checkbox from the view here.
        cbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                // do what ever you want.
            }
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

check below code it may help you.

```
private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return main_genral_class.review_name.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListContent holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.review_row, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.check_date = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2);




                holder.img.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);
                holder.name.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener1);
                holder.check_date.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener2);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text2.setText(main_genral_class.review_shout.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

---

```
private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v
                    .getParent());

                Toast.makeText(review_activity.this, "click on Image View",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
```

---

```
private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener1 = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v
                        .getParent());

                    Toast.makeText(review_activity.this, "click on Text View",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
```

---

```
private OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener2 = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v
                        .getParent());

                    Toast.makeText(review_activity.this, "click on Date Text View",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
```