# gridview inside sherlockfragment cannot perform onItemClick

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-gridview

I have seen many post regarding this but cannot understand y my code doesn't work.

i have a gridview in SherlockFragment and i updating the gridview items in an asyncTask.

Here is my xml for gridView,

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
android:padding="4dip"
android:background="#000000"
 />
```

and GridView items xml is.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cat_thumbnail"
    android:background="#80a0a0a0"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

and the code that i am using is.,

```
extends SherlockFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) (v.findViewById(R.id.gridview));
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    CategoryItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new GridImages().execute();
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            tempMap = CategoryItems.get(position);
            String Catid = tempMap.get(TAG_ID);
            Fragment videoFragment = new VideosFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(TAG_ID, Catid);
            videoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentChangeActivity fca = (FragmentChangeActivity) getActivity();
            fca.switchContent(videoFragment);
        }
    });

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView thumbnail;
    }

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.category_list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);
            holder.title.setSelected(false);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.cat_thumbnail);
            holder.thumbnail.setSelected(false);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            view=(View) convertView;
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        tempMap = CategoryItems.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(tempMap.get(TAG_NAME));
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.thumbnail,
                defaultOptions);
                    holder.title.setOnClickListener(forItemClick);
        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(forItemClick);
        return view;
    }
}
  private OnClickListener forItemClick=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "kjsdhkfds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

class GridImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            CategoryFragment.this.getActivity());

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        parsing();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private void parsing() {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url.trim());
    try {
        JSONObject Collection = json.getJSONObject(TAG_HEADER);
        Category = Collection.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORY);
        for (int i = 0; i < Category.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject temp = Category.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = temp.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = temp.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String thumbnail = temp.getString(TAG_THUMBNAIL);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_THUMBNAIL, thumbnail);

            CategoryItems.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int i = 0;
    imageUrls = new String[CategoryItems.size()];
    for (HashMap<String, String> map : CategoryItems) {
        imageUrls[i] = map.get(TAG_THUMBNAIL).trim();
        System.out.println(imageUrls[i]);
        i++;
    }
    defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.logo).resetViewBeforeLoading()
            .cacheOnDisc().build();

    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(
            defaultOptions).build();
    imageLoader.init(config);
}
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong., i cannot find it.,

i cannot perform onClick event for my gridView.

I **I have updated my code now works., but this will not be the final solution i think because i didn't made the gridview clickable.valuable comments are expected always Thaks @Dhaval Sodha Parmar.,**

Comment: did you able to see the images in grid ?

Comment: yes., i can populate items to that gridview that is fine

Comment: onActivityCreated make sure this function is getting called

Comment: i am calling the asynctask in that function , and it working . right!
then y that onClick is not working?

Comment: HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
tempMap = CategoryItems.get(position); u don have to create a new instance of hashMap every time avoid it this is not the solution, adn also put some log inside the click to make sure that it is not getting called

Comment: no the onItemClick is never called., i tried.

Comment: write your onItemClickListener after you set the adapter in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: that also i tried but no response @Santhosh

Comment: okay. wait i will check. that has worked for me. i will check what has to be added or changed.

Comment: okay @Santhosh, i am waiting

Comment: your alternet option chekc this---> http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264218/1168654

Answer (score 0):

write your onItemClickListener after you set the adapter in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask as shown below.

```
class GridImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //your background task code
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        //add the below line
       gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView);

       gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

       /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        }
      });*/

     gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried that too., but the onitemClick event not working

Comment: Check now. I would have not posted it as answer if it was not working for me.

Comment: Add a Log Statement and check whether it prints something. The same approach works for both listView and GridView and I have used ABS itself. The only line which i haven't written in my apps is setRetainInstance(true); but i don't know if that is a problem. also, instead of having the GridView itself as the root element i have placed in inside a Relative layout as i have other Controls also.

Comment: then y my code doesn't work. is there anything wrong in my xml code ah? please review my full code.@Santhosh

Comment: Let me know, If nothing what i have suggested has worked for you. i will be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26511/discussion-between-tamilselvan-and-santhosh)